# Свернуть окно MainWindow через вызов js кода в QtWebEngine в C++

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, qt5, qtwebengine

Есть проблема. Когда я хочу вызвать js-код html-кнопки, который вызывает С++ функцию, все проходит успешно - кроме одного, я никак не могу нормально взаимодействовать с MainWindow (от QMainWindow), мои попытки вызывать сворачивание окна или растягивание ни к чему не приводят. В чем может быть проблема?
Код исправно выполняется, н-р спокойно пишет в qDebug что функция была вызывана.

Если использовать просто pushButton от qt, то все работает исправно.(сделал в качестве проверки)

UP:

**webconnect.cpp**

```
webconnect::minimize_Window()
{
   MainWindow w;
   w.showMinimized(); //не работает
}
```

**webconnect.h**

```
#ifndef webconnect_h
#define webconnect_h

#include <QObject>

class webconnect : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Q_INVOKABLE void minimize_Window();

};
#endif
```

**main.js**

```js
var webChannel = new QWebChannel(qt.webChannelTransport, function(channel) {  
});
function minimize_Window(){
     webChannel.objects.jscpp.minimize_Window();
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    MainWindow MainW;
     MainW.setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::CustomizeWindowHint);
     MainW.show();

    return app.exec();       
}
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
     QMainWindow(parent),
     ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{

     ui->setupUi(this);

     webobj = new webconnect();
     channel = new QWebChannel(this);
     channel->registerObject("jscpp", webobj);
     ui->webEngineView->page()->setWebChannel(channel);
     ui->webEngineView->page()->load(QUrl(QString("qrc:/index.html"))); 
                                          

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{

    delete ui;

}
```

**index.html**

```
...
<i class="far fa-minus-square" onclick="minimize_Window()"></i>
...
```

Comment: Приведите [mre]

Comment: @dIm0n Забыл добавить, добавил.

Comment: @sepera_okeq, передавайте в конструктор `webconnect` указатель на `MainWindow`

Comment: @Maxim Timakov А можете дать пример грамотного указателя и я так понял что стоит через сигналы-слоты делать?

Comment: @Maxim Timakov А вроде разобрался. Спасибо за подсказку в решении вопроса.